# Not Specifying CSS Width in Chrome Causing Div Resizing Issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

I have this setup:

```
<div id="appBody">
     <div id="appLeftPane">
         <div id="resizer">

         </div>
     </div>
     <div id="appRightPane">

     </div>
<div>
```

The `resizer` is tied to a jQuery resizing function.

CSS:

```
#appBody {
    float: left;
    min-height: 650px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1200px;
    background: #fefefe;
}

#appLeftPane {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#appRightPane {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 650px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid #cecece;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#resizer {
    width:300px; 
    height:100%; 
    min-height: 650px; 
    float: left;   
}
```

The content on the left side is kept in that `div` (not `#appLeftPane`).  When you resize the content to the right, thereby shrinking the `#appRightPane` `div`, I have it set to `overflow:auto`.  This works to the effect on all browsers except for Chrome for Windows.

On Chrome, because I did not set a width on the `#appRightPane`, it is only about 100px wide, the rest is hidden.  All the other browsers sets that div to 100% of the remaining width.

If I remove the overflow properties, then it DOES show in Chrome, but in Chrome and all the rest of the browsers, the entire div bumps below the left div which is bad. (Same thing happens when I try to set a width or min-width).

Can anyone see what is happening?

Comment: Maybe add `display:inline-block` to left and right divs. You should make a fiddle so we can see the problem.

Comment: I attempted to add a fiddle

Comment: Well in your fiddle example the right div is resizing just fine in chrome, so you havn't recreated the problem.

Comment: @slynagh  Yeah, I saw that; not sure why I couldn't create it.  I did get a fix finally; see the answer I added.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Chrome has some sort of a bug with overflow and hiding content.

I simply did this and problem was fixed:

`clear: right` on `#appRightPane`.

Clearing the right seemed to push the width of the div all the way open (to the right).  This had no negative impact on other browsers.